# Composing email(gmail) from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, email, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a chrome extension which basically has a button , on click which opens the Gmail compose mail popup, with subject/body filled with static text content everytime.

I tried reading Gmail APIs, but couldn't get far.

If anyone has worked on any such thing, please guide me.
I am still amateur at this.

Comment: Question is too broad. requires many steps and concepts regarding extensions, dom and javascript. look some more at the docs and show us an attempt and whats not working. note you can also simply build an anchor with parameters and open a new compose window, but it would open as a new tab, not a popup inside gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this link -

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=someone@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=someone.else@example.com
```

This is the gmail link to compose an email.

Is this what you where looking for?

Comment: Thanks Jacob , had no idea it was this simple since the content of the mail is static all the time.
Do you have any idea how I can automate the sending of the mail, once it is composed?

Comment: No problem. Are you talking about sending the email automatically without a human user, maybe like a response to some one creating an account or a reminder of some sort?